# How do I target tab within a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tabs

How do I target `tab-1` with jQuery, but only if the `#flexTab` has the class `.publications`. I have another set of tabs on the site and I don't want it to affect those hence the class `.publications`.

```html
<ul id="flexTab" role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills nav-fill d-flex justify-content-center publications">
    <li class="col-lg-4 p-0">
        <a class="nav-link text-center tab-1 active" href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-selected="true ">Briefing Papers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 p-0">
        <a class="nav-link text-center tab-2 " href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-2" aria-selected="false ">Academic Papers</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried

```js
$("#flexTab .publications .tab-1").click(function() {
```

And

```js
$("#flexTab, .publications, .tab-1").click(function() {
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't have another set of tabs with `id="flexTab"`.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you just need someone to point out the obvious. I'm using a WordPress template, so I appended the post id onto #flexTab.

Answer (score 0):

To specify selectors that apply to the same element, you don't put a space between them. So it should be

```
$("#flexTab.publications .tab-1")
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Probably because the ID selector always selects the first element with that ID, due to the uniqueness requirement. It won't look for a later one that has the `publications` class.

Comment: Can you leave out the ID, and just use `.publications .tab-1`?